# Applying SpaceAfter/SpaceBefore to a Placeholder

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2016

I can't figure out how to increase/decrease the space between paragraphs for Textbox content that comes from a placeholder.

If I type multiple paragraphs of text directly into a Textbox, the SpaceBefore/SpaceAfter settings control the space between paragraphs as expected. This doesn't work when I have a Textbox with a placeholder that loads multiple paragraphs of text. I see that the placeholder has its own formatting settings, but I don't see one that is equivalent to SpaceBefore/SpaceAfter.

It's entirely possible I've misunderstood how each property works. I use SpaceAfter to control space after each line feed/carriage return. I use LineHeight to affect the space between all lines of text.
Also, there is no HTML involved.

I feel like I must be missing something simple or is this really going to be a challenge, lol?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

> If I type multiple paragraphs of text directly into a Textbox, the SpaceBefore/SpaceAfter settings control the space between paragraphs as expected. This doesn't work when I have a Textbox with a placeholder that loads multiple paragraphs of text. I see that the placeholder has its own formatting settings, but I don't see one that is equivalent to SpaceBefore/SpaceAfter.

That's because it's not possible to use formatting to separate paragraphs in a Placeholder. It does not have a concept of multiple paragraphs. As per the docs on [Formatting Placeholders and Static Text in a Text Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/formatting-text-and-placeholders-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16#formatting-placeholders-and-static-text-in-a-text-box), this is only possible in regular text boxes:

> **Unlike placeholder text**, you can align individual text in a text box separately, **use multiple paragraphs** within a single text box, and define other behavior for any subset of text

And:

> You can also use multiple paragraphs inside a single text box.

But what I believe you can do is artificially create paragraphs and break them up via [HTML code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-html-into-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16). You would need to wrap each paragraph in a set of `<p>` and `</p>` tags wherever you want the paragraphs to have spacing between them. Unfortunately this means you'd likely have to store that HTML code in the source of where your paragraphs are pulled from.

Please note you have to change the Placeholder markup type to HTML, as per the linked docs above:

> By default, a placeholder represents plain text, so you will need to change the placeholder mark-up type to HTML.

I believe this is a property of the Placeholder itself.

Comment: I was afraid this would be true. I don't love how Microsoft explains this, though. What I'm doing is not similar to highlighting blocks of text in the Textbox and formatting them in different ways. The SpaceBefore/SpaceAfter is applied to the entire Textbox. The Placeholder supports a Carriage Return/LineFeed which is all a paragraph is. Bummer and thank you.